# MS Access VBA: Sending an email through Outlook

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

How can I send an email through an account using MS Access VBA? I know this question is vague but it's so hard to find the relevant information online that isn't outdated in some way.

EDIT: I don't mean to be rude to those who are answering, but **I am using MS Access**. I cannot write the actual code in Outlook VBA.

Comment: there is ton of info on this site that isnt outdated that answers your question.  Open google and type in Stackoverflow Send outlook email.

Comment: I have looked but no luck

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add a reference to the Outlook object model in the Visual Basic editor.  Then you can use the code below to send an email using outlook.

```
Sub sendOutlookEmail()
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oMail.Body = "Body of the email"
oMail.Subject = "Test Subject"
oMail.To = "Someone@somewhere.com"
oMail.Send
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Again I am using MS Access.

Comment: you need to explain what is not working. Do you have the security turned off to run macros within Access? Do you have outlook installed. Are you receiving an error message? What version of office are you using. I wrote this in access and tested from access.  did you add a reference to the object model?  And to the person who down voted, how is this not useful?

Comment: I must correct myself, apologies. This code only works when I run it while Outlook is open manually. I want to technically automate the process (right now I run this database on the Task Scheduler, and I want it to send off emails every morning etc), but I also want to choose what account it's coming from.

Comment: I am sure someone will come help but I am done helping on this thread due to the down vote of my very valid answer to your original question.

Comment: If it helps any, I was not the downvoter. I will go ahead and accept this since it does answer my question.

Comment: I wrote another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976340/sending-email-through-ms-access-vba-outlook-choosing-sending-profile

Comment: @Sorceri Your answer works well for me, just want to clarify one thing, the code opens a new outlook email window, and also sends the email in the "background", is there a way to disable it from opening the window and just sending that email in the background?

Comment: @DavidMorin You will need to use FindWindow and ShowWindow in the Windows API to hide the Outlook Window.  FindWindow to get the window handle to Outlook and then ShowWindow(hwnd, 0) to hide it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is email code I used in one of my databases. I just made variables for the person I wanted to send it to, CC, subject, and the body. Then you just use the DoCmd.SendObject command. I also set it to "True" after the body so you can edit the message before it automatically sends.

```
Public Function SendEmail2()

Dim varName As Variant          
Dim varCC As Variant            
Dim varSubject As Variant      
Dim varBody As Variant          

varName = "james@yahoo.com"
varCC = "billy@gmail.com, joe@yahoo.com"
'separate each email by a ','

varSubject = "Hello"
'Email subject

varBody = "Let's get ice cream this week"

'Body of the email
DoCmd.SendObject , , , varName, varCC, , varSubject, varBody, True, False
'Send email command. The True after "varBody" allows user to edit email before sending.
'The False at the end will not send it as a Template File

End Function
```

Comment: "Microsoft Office Access can't send this email message"

Comment: Are you getting the error message from the DoCmd.SendObject command?

Comment: Yes *random characters*

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly or did you modify it? Because I just ran the code I posted again and it worked properly. If you did modify it, post it so I can see what you changed.

Comment: I copied it and just replaced the emails with my own

Comment: Did you put commas in between the emails?

Comment: docmd.sendobject , , , "myemail@somedomain.com", , , "subject", "msg", True, False

Comment: I just ran the code you sent me and it worked too. You are trying to send the email through outlook right? Because my code works with outlook.

Comment: I am using MS Access, I am writing this code to be executed on another account so I can't write it in Outlook