# Sending email through MS Access VBA / Outlook, choosing sending profile

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am looking at this snippet of code from another question here (MS Access VBA): https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975507/1085885

Right now this code only works when I run it while Outlook is open. Is there any way for this code to "open Outlook" and then run all the sending code?

Secondly, how can I choose which Outlook profile to send from? I have access to a couple different profiles and it's sending from my main top inbox but I want it to come from my second inbox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Access VBA: Sending an email through Outlook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973549/ms-access-vba-sending-an-email-through-outlook)

Comment: It's not a duplicate; it's a followup question with a different scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log to the specified profile (as shown in "Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles", if that is what you mean by "profile"). After creating an instance of the Outlook application

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
```

add something like the following:

```
set oNS = oApp.GetNamespace.Logon
oNS.Logon("MyProfileName")
```

Note if Outlook is already running, `Logon` will do nothing. You will need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi or a MAPI wrapper like [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author, use [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).Logon) to log to a specified profile.

If by "profile" you actually mean a different account in the same profile in Outlook, you can set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property to specify a particular account.

If you are sending from an Exchange mailbox, and you need to set a different sender, set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property to the name of the user on whose behalf you are sending (assuming you have the right to send on behalf of that user).

Comment: How do I use the SendUsingAccount property? I do have the MailItem created (see the code)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim bStarted As Boolean
Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem

On Error Resume Next


'Get Outlook if it's running
Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    'Outlook wasn't running, start it from code
    Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    bStarted = True
End If

'Create a new mailitem
Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oItem
    'Set the recipient for the new email
   .To = "receiver@gmail.com"

    .Send
End With

If bStarted Then
'    'If we started Outlook from code, then close it
    oOutlookApp.Quit
End If

'Clean up
Set oItem = Nothing
Set oOutlookApp = Nothing



End Sub
```