# Sending a text message in Outlook with .net

Tags: .net, email, text, outlook

This is the first time I've asked a question on here, so apologies if anything is unclear.

I'm using a .net application to read and send email with Outlook. This is the done with the Outlook object library with the code below:

```
Private Sub SendEmail(ByVal Message As String, ByVal EmailAddress As String)
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
    objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        With objOutlookMsg
            .To = EmailAddress
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .Body = Message
            .Send()
        End With
        objOutlookMsg = Nothing
        objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Outlook 2010 supports sending text messages. I've set this up and I can send a text message manually from the Outlook application. My question is how do I adapt the code above to send a text message instead of an email? The Createitem array doesn't have a "text message" object and I couldn't find any examples elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
With objOulookMsg
    .To = EmailAddress
    .Recipients.ResolveAll()
    .Subject = "Subject"
    ' .BodyFormat = outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain 
    ' symbolic constant olFormatPlain not known without Outlook project reference!
    .BodyFormat = 1    
    .Body = Message
End With
```

Look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/97b21432-77e7-4693-aed6-2cc861703594/create-outlook-message-from-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral) or [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a47815d-2b7e-4002-8368-50d5449170f6/easiest-way-to-send-email?forum=Vsexpressvb) for a more detailed explanation and how to work with VB project project references to `Outlook`.

Property `BodyFormat` defines the format of the mail item. Property `Body` is used for the text format. But `HTML` and `RichText` mails also keep a text representation of the mail in property `Body`.

If you add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` via `Project Menu, Add Reference COM Type Libary` `Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library` (assuming Outlook 2010) and then add the following line at the top of your code

```
Imports outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
```

`Visual Basic` will "know" all `Outlook` classes, properties, methods and constants and allow you to access and use everything using Intellisense.

Comment: The problem I'm still having is that the program crashes at the Send()  command. When I type a mobile number instead of an email address it says "Outlook does not recognize one or more names." I assume the error is because it doesn't recognise the mobile number as a valid recipient. However, when I try it in the Outlook application, it works perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: Outlook usually is configured to use address lists and contact folders to resolve recipients. It might help to ".save()" the mail item before resolving the recipients. See here: http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/02/20/outlook-recipients-collection/

Comment: Unfortunately it made no difference. Do you think perhaps it won't resolve because it's trying to send it from my email account? I think the text messaging is set up on a different account. If you think this would help, do you know how to change the account it sends from? I'll see if I can figure it out...

Comment: Yes, Outlook takes your default mail account. If you want it to use a different account, you'll have to execute an explicit logon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976340/sending-email-through-ms-access-vba-outlook-choosing-sending-profile