# Generating Email with Hyperlink from MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, hyperlink, ms-access-2010

I'm attempting to generate an email from MS Access when a particular procedure is run and certain conditions are met, the email will include a hyperlink. I've found the sendobject macro command does not allow for hyperlink, only static text. It seems that the solution is to code the portion of the entire process that generates and sends the email in VBA and call on that code in the appropriate segment of my if function within my macro.

I can't figure out the appropriate code to generate and send and email with a hyperlink to an individual however. It will be very simple, single recepient, unchanging title, and the body will read 'New providers require designation, please access the **provider designation dashboard** for provider designation' ideally the provider designation dashboard would be the hyperlink and point to a shared network space.

What commands do I need to accomplish this, I'm inexperienced in VBA and this is eating up a fair amount of time I don't have.

Thank you

Comment: Use HTMLBody for the email then add as a link using HTML tags

Comment: Are you running Outlook to send and receive mails?

Comment: Perhaps using vba instead of a macros will help - include the hyperlink in the text of the email. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973549/ms-access-vba-sending-an-email-through-outlook

Comment: I am running outlook. Sticking to VBA and using htmlbody for the email reference is the proper solution, I'm just very unfamiliar with VBA at this point. I guess this is my time to start learning a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some different approaches for sending e-mail with code. The code bellow uses an Outlook Application COM object to generate the message with a hyperlink - thus, it will only work if MS Outlook is installed in the user's machine.

```
Sub NewEmail(ByVal mylink As String, ByVal therecipient As String)

    Dim Outlook As Object, Email As Object 
    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = Outlook.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem = 0

    With Email
        .Subject = "My Subject" 'message subject
        .HTMLBody = "Greetings, please check this link: <a href='" & mylink & "'>Click me</a>." 'message body, in html. concatenate multiple strings if you need to
        .To = therecipient   'recipient

        'use this if you want to generate the message and show it to the user
        .Display

        'use this instead if you want the mail to be sent directly
        '.Send

    End With

    Set Email = Nothing
    Set Outlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Put the code in a module. Then anywhere in your code you may call the procedure with something like:

```
NewEmail "www.mysite.com/targetpage.html", "persontomail@domain.com"
```

Notice that the routine above uses [late binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115). To use early binding (and get intellisese, but with some drawbacks), you would have to add a reference to Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library and dim the "Outlook" and "Email" objects as Outlook.Application and Outlook.MailItem, respectively.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not proposing the above code as a ready solution for your actual scenario, just as something you could start with to build your own solution