# Sending Email from Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am trying to develop a database where teachers log an application for when they need a lesson to be covered (I'd do this in SQL but I can't currently).

I would like the database to notify a certain member of staff when an application is made. Selecting the member of staff would be done from a combobox, driven by a query. The reason for the query is that I only want specific members of staff to receive this notification - essentially those who manage other staff.

Once that member of staff has been selected, I want the person making the application to click a button, which will then fire an email to the person selected in the combobox.

I get a flicker of Outlook doing something and then nothing.

This is what I have so far, with the DLookup using the staff member selected in the combobox to then find the email address in the Staff table:

```vb
Private Sub Command788_Click()
    Dim Email_Note As Variant
    Email_Note = DLookup("Email", "Staff", Forms![Cover Application Form]!Combo767)
    Dim olLook As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNewEmail As Outlook.CreateItem
    Dim StrContactEmail As String
    Set olLook = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNewEmail = olLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    strEmailSubject = "Application for Cover: Line Manager Notification"
    strEmailText = "Something in here..."
    StrContactEmail = "Email_Note"
    olNewEmail.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll make that change. I'm now clicking the command button and getting no response. Sure I did yesterday. What do you reckon to the rest?

Comment: I think you need to put a breakpoint in the code and examine olLook

Comment: `Dim olNewEmail As Outlook.CreateItem` should be `Outlook.MailItem`

Comment: In addition, your `strEmail` variables don't do anything. Look here for a start: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17973549/3820271

Comment: hey @DavidMeller, here on Stackoverflow, things like 'thanks', 'greetings', 'hello', 'thank you' are not really apreciated, since they add 'noise' to the Q&A system. I've edited them out for you, in future question, don't use them. Thank you

Comment: @Mafii - duly noted. I'm new to this game.

Comment: @DavidMeller, thats why I wrote this. Your question seems pretty accurate and good, so people were able to help you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ensure that the Outlook library is referenced in the tools tab of VBA Editor. It also looks like you created strings for the body and subject but didn't declare them. Instead of declaring them as string variables just set the `outlook. body` etc. to the appropriate string as I have shown below.

You don't need to encapsulate `email_note` with quotes once you have declared it as a variable. I assumed that was an email address?

The `strContactEmail` is no longer needed, I don't see where it is used.

```
Private Sub Command788_Click()
Dim Email_Note As Variant
Email_Note = DLookup("Email", "Staff", Forms![Cover Application Form]!Combo767)
Dim olLook As Outlook.Application
Dim olNewEmail As Outlook.mailItem
'Dim StrContactEmail As String
Set olLook = New Outlook.Application
Set olNewEmail = olLook.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
   olNewEmail.Subject="Application for Cover: Line Manager Notification" 
   olNewEmail.Body = "Something in here..."
   olNewEmail.To = email_note
   olNewEmail.Send
Set olNewEmail = Nothing
Set olLook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Oooh okay - I'll give this a good look now and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: And yes - Email_Note will be the email address returned by the DLookup. Or that's the idea, anyway.

Comment: Again, `Dim olNewEmail As Outlook.CreateItem` should be `Outlook.MailItem`. :)

Comment: I've made the changes and it seems to want to kick Outlook into action but  on the taskbar on the right, I get the Outlook icon and then a cog on it. From there it then says 'Outlook Is Closing'. Is this a security issue?

Comment: @DavidMeller: Have you allowed "Programmatic Access" in security settings? http://www.slipstick.com/developer/change-programmatic-access-options/

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed that's worked! Wonderful.